# Fix character encoding in csv http response file in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, csv, express, express-router

I have an API which gives me a CSV file as a response, however a lot of the content is in French and it has special characters are being screwed up. Stuff like this is appearing on the CSV files: `Example√© of Wei√©√©rdness√©√©`

Is there a way to standardize the characters to be ANSI Latin I? My endpoints are implemented with express and I simply do a call to the database and use `csv-express` to set the response as a csv type.

```js
router.get('/', async (req, res) => {
  const result = await MyDbSession.query(`
  SELECT * FROM my_table;
`)

  res.csv(result)
})
```

Edit: One thing I tried to do is set `res.charset` and `res.set('content-type', 'text/csv; charset=iso-8859-1')`, which do not seem to work. Basically the following was tried, but made no difference:

```js
...
  res.charset = 'Latin-1' // or 'iso-8859-1'
  res.csv(result)
})
```

or

```js
...
  res.set('content-type', 'text/csv; charset=iso-8859-1')
  res.csv(result)
})
```

Answer (score 0):

If you have access to the database implementation you could try to update the charset which is currently used to UTF-8 to standardize your responses.

Comment: So this has to be done on the database level? It couldn't just be set in the response?